# Calculating the threshold date - Qliksense function

Tags: join, qlikview, qliksense

So I have a data which is in the following format:

| Order ID | Order Date | Order Qty | Threshold Qty | Cummulative Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Day1 | 5 | 9 | 5 |
| 2 | Day2 | 5 | 9 | 10 |
| 3 | Day3 | 6 | 9 | 16 |

I want to create a new column called "Threshold Date", which should contain the value:

| Threshold Date |
| --- |
| Null |
| Day2 |
| Day2 |

Which comes from the relation that it will be the first date when the net `Cumulative Sum` goes over the `Threshold Qty`. This function can be implemented in Python easily by taking a variable which holds the fixed value.

Is there any Qlik Sense function or method in which can be helpful to solve the following problem? I am relatively new to Qlik Sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script below should give you the expected result (check out the screenshot).

One way to solve this is to check for each row:

- if the previous value for `Threshold Date` <sup>1</sup> is `null` <sup>2</sup>

  - if its **not** then return the last loaded/previous value for `Threshold Date`
  - it its empty then check if the current value of `Cummulative Sum` is greater than the current value of `Threshold Qty`

    - if `true` then return the current value of `Order Date`
    - if `false` return `null`

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> is possible to reference new field while creating the new field but only in the context of its previous value. Thats why `peek([Threshold Date])` can be used while `[Threshold Date]` is being created (aka not loaded from a previous table)</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> In Qlik (Sense and View) `-1` is `true` and `0` is `false`. More info [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2023/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/NULLFunctions/IsNull.htm).</sup>

<sup><sup>3</sup> More about `peek()` function [here](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2023/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm).</sup>

```
Load 
  *,
    if(
        IsNull(peek([Threshold Date])) = 0, 
        peek([Threshold Date]),
        if(
            [Cummulative Sum] > [Threshold Qty],
            [Order Date], 
            null())
    ) as [Threshold Date]
;
Load * Inline [
Order ID, Order Date, Order Qty, Threshold Qty, Cummulative Sum
1       , Day1      , 5        , 9            , 5
2       , Day2      , 5        , 9            , 10
3       , Day3      , 6        , 9            , 16
];
```

And the resulting table will be:
[image: Result]